# Busca simples FIREBASE

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-database

Estou fazendo um teste no `firebase` e estou com dificuldades para recuperar os dados do banco com JS.
A estrutura da tabela é a seguinte:

```
Scores
    - key
        - name
        - points
    - key
        - name
        - points
```

O que eu quero é retornar os scores de determinado nome por exemplo, mas só quero recuperar todos os dados e manipulá-los, não quero ligar aqueles listeners `child_added`, `child_removed`. É possível fazer isso?

Tentei isso:

```
firebase.database().ref('scores').orderByChild('name').equalTo('Fulano');
```

E me retorna um objeto do firebase, mas não sei manipular ele e nem se está correta essa busca.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você pode ver melhor nesse [link (documentação)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data?hl=pt-br#reading_and_writing_lists), para trabalhar com os dados retornados pelo firebase é necessário utilizar a função **.on()**, que recebe um evento e uma função,que será executada a medida que os dados vão sendo recuperados.

```
let consulta = firebase.database().ref('scores').orderByChild('name').equalTo('Fulano');
consulta.on('child_added', function(data) {
    console.log(data.val().name);
    console.log(data.val().points);
});
```

Sendo **'child_added'** um evento para recuperar listas de itens ou detectar adições a uma lista de itens.